# Isn't it bad practice to tell the user that a username doesn't exist e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org

Tags: security, authentication, standards

I was always under the impression that whenever you provide a login interface and the user does not provide valid credentials you never confirm which of the username and password was incorrect as this can aid hacking attempts?

It would seem that [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org) go against this standard of practices;

[image]

Comment: It's wikipedia. Anyone can edit it... Maybe don't get your information from there.

Comment: Usernames in wikipedia.org are public. You can always check this URL to see if a username already exists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Paul.ccc

Comment: Why don't you ask them? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contact_us

Comment: This is more a security question than programming.  See [Is there any reason to show the same message for invalid username as password?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/13079/1369)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is case-specific.

On one hand, you have public-usernames such as in websites that host forums such as StackOverflow and, in your example, Wikipedia. The term "public", in this sense, is used to mean that it is used as a public identifier for all to see. In these cases, it wouldn't make any sense to mask the fact that a username exists or not in a login form - this information is publicly accessible. Be it a page to view specific user's information or even by scanning every page on the website - you'd be able to enumerate a full list of users (at least, those that have contributed) with little effort.

On the other hand, you have private-usernames, such as ones used in banking applications. As a bank website would not (or at least, should never) display actual usernames on their site to anyone anywhere - the username is used purely as a website-identifier and authentication tool. In this case, it makes good sense to give a warning such as "*The username/password combination you used is invalid.*" opposed to "*The username you entered does not exist.*".

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to crawl user pages to get a list of all users on Wikipedia: [they're all here in a convenient list.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ListUsers)